# Set default permissions for newly created subdirectories in the folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I want set default permissions only for newly created subdirectories in the folder, not for the newly created files in some folder.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you search for is a command `umask`. It permit you to set the default permissions when create file or directory. For more information you can refer to [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/umask.1p.html).

The `umask` can be in numerical or symbol form:

```
umask a=rx,ug+w
umask 002
```

**But you can't split the functionality only for directories and not for files.**

P.S. You can use `mkdir` with `-m` to set specific mask:

```
[root@rhel9-1 tmp]# mkdir 1
[root@rhel9-1 tmp]# mkdir -m 700 2
[root@rhel9-1 tmp]# ls -ld 1 2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Apr 22 12:10 1
drwx------ 2 root root 6 Apr 22 12:10 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The permissions of a newly-created file or directory are set by a) the permissions the creating process asks, b) modified by the file creation mask (umask) of the creating process (inherited from the parent process, so sort of per-user), or the default ACL on the directory if there is one.

The latter ones can't be specified differently for directories and files, but what the application asks when creating a file or directory often is different depending on which one is being created. That is, regular files are created with permissions `0666`, and directories with permissions `0777`. Except for files that are meant to be executable, which would also be created with permissions `0777`. The umask or default ACL would then reduce those permissions; neither can add permissions, so e.g. `ssh-keygen` can create private key files with `0600` and be sure no other users have access to the file.

I'm not exactly sure what the point would be for files to have different permissions than directories, other than for executability. Usually, it would be the same users who need access to all files and subdirectories created within the same logical location.